# Creating dll from multiple classes in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, class, dll

I can not figure out how to create a dll from several classes. In qt creator I create a "Library" project, add several classes there, but the project is not built and dll files are not created. Moreover, if you use a purely one class, then everything is fine. But the problem is that my class includes headers of other classes
For example there is Class A and Class B which includes the heading Class A.

ClassB.h

```
#include "ClassA.h"
```

Comment: maybe you need to add ClassA.cpp to .pro file.
are you can share the full source code?

Comment: I add ClassA.cpp to .pro file and this works! Thank you very mutch!